# ruby: sort! and uniq! Which to run first?

Tags: ruby

I need to run both `sort!` and `uniq!` on an array.  Which is better to run first?  Or is there a way to combine these into one command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I made a little benchmark test with different combinations of uniq uniq! sort and sort!
There are no significant differences:

```
                user     system      total        real
sort!.uniq!103.547000   0.172000 103.719000 (104.093750)
uniq!.sort!100.437000   0.093000 100.530000 (100.859375)
uniq.sort 100.516000   0.157000 100.673000 (101.031250)
sort.uniq 103.563000   0.062000 103.625000 (103.843750)
```

What you may not use is something like:

```
array = [1]
array.uniq!.sort!
```

uniq! will result in nil and sort! will throw an exception.

The benchmark I used:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'date'

TEST_LOOPS = 10_000
ARRAY = []
1000.times{ 
  ARRAY << Date.new(1900 + rand(100), rand(11)+1, rand(27) + 1 ) 
}
Benchmark.bm(10) {|b|

  b.report('sort!.uniq!') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      a = ARRAY.dup
      a.sort!
      a.uniq!
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('uniq!.sort!') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      a = ARRAY.dup
      # uniq!.sort! not possible. uniq! may get nil
      a.uniq!
      a.sort!
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('uniq.sort') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      a = ARRAY.dup.uniq.sort
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

  b.report('sort.uniq') {
   TEST_LOOPS.times { 
      a = ARRAY.dup.sort.uniq
   }            #Testloops
  }             #b.report

} #Benchmark
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a benchmark test and for pointing out the potential problem with `.uniq!.sort!`

Comment: This is not a good benchmark because the performance difference between `.uniq.sort!` and `.sort!.uniq!` is highly dependent on the data being sorted. You're testing the same pseudorandom array over and over again, so if it has very few duplicate elements (which I think is the case here), the effect of `uniq` will be negligible.

Comment: This is also in the other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21376982/676874 . (and I would recommend the asker to accept the other answer).

Answer (score 10):

In fact, it depends from the number of unique values. 
In the example of knut, the start set could include at most 365 unique values out of 1000, and the order of operations seemed without influence.

if 'uniq' significantly reduces the array size, there is a distinct advantage in running it first.

```
A=[]
10_000.times do
  A << rand(80)
end

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report "sort.uniq" do
    10_000.times {A.sort.uniq}
  end
  b.report "uniq.sort" do
    10_000.times {A.uniq.sort}
  end
end

                 user     system      total        real
sort.uniq   20.202000   0.281000  20.483000 ( 20.978098)
uniq.sort    9.298000   0.000000   9.298000 (  9.355936)
```

I did not test the '.uniq!.sort!' permutations, but I believe that they should follow the above result.

This example may be a little extreme, but I do not see why one should not always run '.uniq' first

Answer (score 5):

It really doesn't matter which way you do this.  I guess the uniq first so it results in less items to sort with one pass through the array.  So you can do

```
 a=[3,3,3,3,6,7,1,1,1,1,3]
 a.uniq!
 a.sort!
```

Comment: Would I need to do `array_name.uniq!.sort!`?  Or is the first `!` unnecessary?

Comment: The first ! is unnecessary because that means it is replacing your original array.  The uniq does not have to replace it because it is passing the return value to sort! which will then replace your original array with the final value.

Comment: That is not true! You first get a copy by `uniq`, and then this copy is replaced by `sort!`. So if you want to sort and make uniq in place, you have to use both `uniq!` and `sort!`. Try it out in irb and test with `equal?`.

Comment: and what would be the practical use for doing that?  The end result is the same

Comment: Ok fair enough if you are truly concerned about doing it in place it should be ! !.  I changed answer thanks.

Comment: @mliebelt and @Michael Would not using both `!` mean the program ends up using more memory, since it is not doing it in place?  (Trying to learn as much as I can)

Comment: You shouldn't combine uniq! and sort! in this sequence, it may end with an exception. Look what happens with _[1].uniq!.sort!_ uniq! returns nil and sort! will will throw an exception. When you first sort! then you could use uniq! afterwords. Or  you splitt it into two calls.

Answer (score 0):

Running one or the other first depends on the needs of your application.

1) Unless you have huge arrays, run the one first that makes the most sense. Are you using the sorted or uniqued array elsewhere? Does one order conform more naturally to the logic of your application.

2) If you have huge arrays, and I mean huge based on a real measured determination that your code is taking too long in running `array.sort!.uniq!` then you might try the other order and see. If you have a lot of duplicates, then `array.uniq!.sort!` might be marginally faster.

3) If you are worried about speed, you'll probably want to use `sort_by`. See for example, https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby/blob/master/code/enumerable/sort-vs-sort_by.rb

Comment: This is an array of `Date`s, so I didn't define the sort (IE I'm just running `array_name.sort!` without `sort{how to sort}`.  Would `sort_by` still be an advantage?  If so, what would I pass into `sort_b`y?

Comment: If you use _array.uniq!.sort!_ you may get an exception. Just try _[1].uniq!.sort!_

Comment: True, `Array#uniq!` returns `nil` if the array is already unique, but doing `array.uniq.sort!` isn't going to accomplish what David asked. `array` won't be sorted.

Comment: The link at the end of your answer leads to a 404. Could you track down the original page you wanted to link to, or otherwise remove the link? Thanks.

Comment: Updated link per request of @samjewell